# How to create click listener in each chrome notification?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I want to create multiple chrome-extension-notifications listener which has each click listener. but I couldn't make it my way.

When I click in one notification, all notifications listener were played. this is **basic_notification.js**

```
function notifyMe() {
    var notificationId = 'notId1';
    var notificationId2 = 'notId2';
    var notificationId3 = 'notId3';

    var opt = {
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
        title: 'anyTitle',
        message: 'anyString'
    };
    chrome.notifications.create(notificationId, opt  , function(notificationId) {
        console.log(notificationId);
    });
    chrome.notifications.create(notificationId2, opt  , function(notificationId2) {
        console.log(notificationId2);
    });
    chrome.notifications.create(notificationId3, opt  , function(notificationId3) {
        console.log(notificationId3);
    });
}
```

This code can create 3 notifications in once.
and I will write listener in each chrome-extension-notifications.

```
chrome.notifications.create(notificationId, opt  , function(notificationId) {
            chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(notificationClicked);
            console.log(notificationId);
        });

function notificationClicked() {
    console.log("The notification1 was clicked");
}
```

This is all code : **notification.js**

```
function notifyMe() {
    var notificationId = 'notId1';
    var notificationId2 = 'notId2';
    var notificationId3 = 'notId3';

    var opt = {
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
        title: 'anyTitle',
        message: 'anyString'
    };
    chrome.notifications.create(notificationId, opt  , function(notificationId) {
        chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(notificationClicked);
        console.log(notificationId);
    });
    chrome.notifications.create(notificationId2, opt  , function(notificationId2) {
        chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(notificationClicked2);
        console.log(notificationId2);
    });
    chrome.notifications.create(notificationId3, opt  , function(notificationId3) {
        chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(notificationClicked3);
        console.log(notificationId3);
    });
}
function notificationClicked() {
    console.log("The not1 was clicked");
}
function notificationClicked2() {
    console.log("The not2 was clicked");
}
function notificationClicked3() {
    console.log("The not3 was clicked");
}
```

I want to have only one when I press one. What should I do?

Comment: Then add just one. Not inside the callback, but in the outer scope. Check the id parameter inside the listener to see which notification was clicked.

Comment: thanks! I'll try and tell you again.

Comment: I added outer scope. but I don't know how to check id parameter inside the listener. when I click notification, It does not clicked the one of notification. chrome only know 'user clicked chrome-extension-notification!', and chrome don't know notification's id.

Comment: As you can see in the documentation, the onClicked callback has a parameter: the id.

Comment: OMG thank you so much